# URL regex that will match /x/y but also just /x

Tags: regex, django

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDv5FIAeyoY), and am getting an 404 error that 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurants/
is not being matched by

```
url(r'^restaurants/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', RestaurantListView.as_view())
```

while http://127.0.0.1:8000/restaurants/x with any x is. How should I rewrite the path to match the url without any additional /x?

...
Error message:

```
Using the URLconf defined in projekt.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
^contact/$
^$
^about/$
^restaurants/(?P<slug>\w+)/$
The current path, restaurants/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: You probably need an optional match `^restaurants/(?P<slug>\w+/?)?$`

Comment: Yes, use an optional group, but you most probably want `r'^restaurants/(?:(?P<slug>\w+)/)?$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is matches `restaurants/` at the start of input, then captured any 1+ word chars into a group "slug" and then requires and matches `/` at the end of the string (`$` is the end of string anchor.)

You need to wrap the optional part with an [**optional**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do):

```
r'^restaurants/(?:(?P<slug>\w+)/)?$'
               ^^^              ^^
```

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of input
- `restaurants/` -  a literal `restaurants/` substring
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching...

  - `(?P<slug>\w+)` - 1+ word chars captured into a `slug` group
  - `/` - a `/` char
- `)?` - ... end of the non-capturing group matches 1 or 0 times
- `$` - end of input.

Answer (score 1):

In django 2

```
path('restuarants/',RestaurantListView.as_view())
```

In django 1

```
url(r'^restaurants/$', RestaurantListView.as_view())
```